# Error: Transforming SpatialPolygons to the CRS of the Raster

Tags: raster, polygon, extract

I want to get the mean of all raster cells in each part of a polygon but I am getting a warning message. My code is:

```
rain <- readOGR(dsn="/Users___.shp", layer="rain")
class(rain)
#SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

region <- readOGR(dsn="/Users___.shp", layer="region")
class(region)
#SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

s <- raster(ncol=90, nrow=90)
extent(s) <- extent(rain)
rain_raster <- rasterize(rain, s)
class(rain_raster)
#RasterLayer

projectRaster(rain_raster, crs = projection(region))
test1 <- extract(rain_raster, region, fun="mean", na.rm=TRUE)
#warning message: Transforming SpatialPolygons to the CRS of the Raster
```

How can I solve for this problem?

Comment: what makes you think it is a problem?

Comment: @IanTurton Is it not a problem? I thought that because I did `projectRaster`, I should not be receiving this warning message.